# weird multiprocessing behavior in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to implement a simple multiprocessing where a dict is filled for a set of values. The function `process` does some simple calculation based on `dict2`. The function looks like this:

```
def process_control_number(fid, dict1, dict2):

    multiprocessing.current_process().authkey = b"passkey"
    print (fid)
    dict1[fid] = process(dict2[fid])
```

First, I tried the following implementation:

```
def main():
    manager = Manager()
    dict1 = manager.dict()
    dict2 = getdict2()

    job = [Process(target=process_control_number, args=(fid, dict1, dict2)) for fid in all_files]


    _ = [p.start() for p in job]
    _ = [p.join() for p in job]
```

but this was actually too slow (Does any one know WHY? It printed one ID every 2-3 seconds). I even tried to remove the calculations and just print the `fid`, but it was still super slow, so I tried to implement this in a different way:

```
def main():
    manager = Manager()
        dict1 = manager.dict()
    dict2 = getdict2()

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(6) 
    for fid in all_files:
        pool.apply_async(process_control_number, args=(fid, dict1, dict2))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

But im getting the following error:

```
Process SpawnPoolWorker-4:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 249, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 108, in worker
    task = get()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 345, in get
    return _ForkingPickler.loads(res)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\multiprocess-0.70.5-py3.6.egg\multiprocess\managers.py", line 837, in RebuildProxy
    return func(token, serializer, incref=incref, **kwds)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\multiprocess-0.70.5-py3.6.egg\multiprocess\managers.py", line 691, in __init__
    self._incref()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\multiprocess-0.70.5-py3.6.egg\multiprocess\managers.py", line 741, in _incref
    conn = self._Client(self._token.address, authkey=self._authkey)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\multiprocess-0.70.5-py3.6.egg\multiprocess\connection.py", line 496, in Client
    answer_challenge(c, authkey)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\multiprocess-0.70.5-py3.6.egg\multiprocess\connection.py", line 742, in answer_challenge
    raise AuthenticationError('digest sent was rejected')
multiprocess.context.AuthenticationError: digest sent was rejected
```

Can someone help with this?